# Detect if Remote Desktop is active with batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, remote-desktop

So, I've been scouring the internet trying to find a way to detect if remote desktop is running.  I really never found what I was looking for, so I set out to do it myself.  I found that when I `query user` I get the following result:

```
 USERNAME          SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>michaelh          rdp-tcp#0           1  Active      none   9/29/2014 11:14 AM
```

So I used a `for loop` to find and break apart the line I needed. Here's what I came up with:

```
@ECHO off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2,4" %%a in ('QUERY USER ^| FINDSTR ">"') DO (

    set "consoleTemp=%%a"
    set "connectionState=%%b"
    set "consoleType=!consoleTemp:~0,7!"

)

SET consoleTypeCorrect=
IF "!consoleType!"=="rdp-tcp" SET consoleTypeCorrect=1

SET connectionStateCorrect=
IF "connectionState"=="Active" SET connectionStateCorrect=1

set TRUE=
set TRUE=%connectionStateCorrect%%consoleTypeCorrect%

IF "%TRUE%"=="11" (
    echo You are connected via !consoleType!
) else (
    ECHO Sorry, the console type is !consoleType!
)

endlocal
PAUSE
```

This works perfectly, but my question for you guys would be is there's a better way of doing this?  If you're looking at this and don't understand how it works, then pm/email me and I'll explain it.

Comment: Based on your messaging it seems you are just checking for the current user.  If so, add the username to the command `query user %username%`.  As for methods, what you have works and is simple, so I do not have any better methods.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann I don't care about who the user is for what I'm doing.  I only need to check if the active connection is rdp. If there were a way to populate the password when using batch to run rdp I would do that, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Another way (as `query` does not work with my Windows): give the command window an unique name: `title UniqueStringToIdentify`, get `tasklist /v |find "UniqueStringToIdentify", process output the same way you did with `query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @David Ruhmann for your input!  I'll post this as my answer if there isn't a better way to detect if RDP is connected.

```
@ECHO off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2,4" %%a in ('QUERY USER ^| FINDSTR ">"') DO (

    set "consoleTemp=%%a"
    set "connectionState=%%b"
    set "consoleType=!consoleTemp:~0,7!"

)

SET consoleTypeCorrect=
IF "!consoleType!"=="rdp-tcp" SET consoleTypeCorrect=1

SET connectionStateCorrect=
IF "connectionState"=="Active" SET connectionStateCorrect=1

set TRUE=
set TRUE=%connectionStateCorrect%%consoleTypeCorrect%

IF "%TRUE%"=="11" (
    echo You are connected via !consoleType!
) else (
    ECHO Sorry, the console type is !consoleType!
)

endlocal
PAUSE
```

Comment: Line
`IF "connectionState"=="Active" SET connectionStateCorrect=1`
should be
`IF "!connectionState!"=="Active" SET connectionStateCorrect=1`